# SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7 (_bio): M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME_Error: no content type

Tags: m2crypto

I have problems loading a pkcs#7 file and ask your help to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I run M2Crypto-0.21.1 with OpenSSL 0.9.8g (as present in Ubuntu 9.4) and built with SWIG 1.3.36 and python 2.6.2.

"python setup.py test --test-suite=tests.test_smime" runs 15 tests with exit status "OK"; so the installation seems to be ok.

I created a pkcs#7 file in PEM format with a digital signature program and tested it with OpenSSL from the command line:

> openssl smime -verify -inform PEM -in mandato-PEM.p7m -noverify

which prints the content contained in the envelope (a text file that I signed) and "Verification successful".  So OpenSSL (same version as used by M2Crypto) seems to like my file.

However, when I try the same in M2Crypto, it chocks right in the beginning on:

> p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7('mandato-PEM.p7m')

I get the following exception:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "./sign.py", line 110, in <module>
> p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7('mandato-PEM.p7m') 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/M2Crypto-0.21.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/M2Crypto/SMIME.py", line 91, in smime_load_pkcs7
> p7_ptr, bio_ptr = m2.smime_read_pkcs7(bio)
> M2Crypto.SMIME.SMIME_Error: no content type
> ```

While I have found information of a problem in Ubuntu (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2010-July/038683.html), it seems to me that this cannot apply here since I built the latest M2Crypto manually and the test suite works fine.

Any help in resolving my problem would be highly appreciated!

many thanks

-bud

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of sweat, here the solution for others who run into the same issue.

I was following the recipe  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/285211/ and found many discussions on the web that just "verify(p7)" [method of SMIME] wasn't correct and "verify(p7, data)" was the right thing to do.

This applies only to SMIME documents where the signature is detached.  My pkcs#7 file, and all other Italian digitally signed documents, are pkcs#7 envelopes that contain both the signature and the file content (in DER format).

Enveloped p7m files have to be verified as follows:

```
s=SMIME.SMIME()    
st = X509.X509_Store()   
st.load_info(trustedCAsPEMfileName)    
s.set_x509_store(st)    
p7bio = BIO.MemoryBuffer(p7strPEM)
p7 = SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio(p7bio)
certStack = p7.get0_signers(X509.X509_Stack())
s.set_x509_stack(certStack)
try:
    docContent = s.verify(p7)
except SMIME.PKCS7_Error, e:
    print "An exception occurred!!!!"
    print e
```

To test that this works, I edited the p7m file such that the signature doesn't verify anymore and it correctly prints out "digest failure".

Answer (score 2):

You can also verify a .p7m file (attached DER format) directly but you need to load PKCS #7 object from DER format by m2 direct call to OpenSSL (`m2.pkcs7_read_bio_der(input_bio._ptr())`) because there is no function for this inside M2Crypto SMIME module. For a proposed patch see [Small patch to SMIME.py](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-crypto/056ggtbbg7/small-patch-to-smime-py).

Here a sample code:

```
import logging

from M2Crypto import SMIME, X509, m2, BIO

certstore_path = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
file_descriptor = open('test_file.p7m', 'rb')
input_bio = BIO.File(file_descriptor)
signer = SMIME.SMIME()
cert_store = X509.X509_Store()
cert_store.load_info(certstore_path)
signer.set_x509_store(cert_store)
try: 
    p7 = SMIME.PKCS7(m2.pkcs7_read_bio_der(input_bio._ptr()), 1)
except SMIME.SMIME_Error, e:
    logging.error('load pkcs7 error: ' + str(e))
sk3 = p7.get0_signers(X509.X509_Stack())
signer.set_x509_stack(sk3)
data_bio = None
try:
    v = signer.verify(p7, data_bio)
except SMIME.SMIME_Error, e:
    logging.error('smime error: ' + str(e))
except SMIME.PKCS7_Error, e:
    logging.error('pkcs7 error: ' + str(e))
```

Code Source: [pysmime core](https://github.com/libersoft/pysmime/blob/master/pysmime/core.py)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to extract the original file from the .p7m one (without verifying it), you need to install M2Crypto with `pip install M2Crypto` (you must probably run `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` before) and then run this Python code:

```py
from M2Crypto import BIO, SMIME, X509

# Load file in memory just to showcase BIO usage
with open('file.p7m', 'rb') as file:
    p7m = file.read()

smime = SMIME.SMIME()
smime.set_x509_store(X509.X509_Store())
smime.set_x509_stack(X509.X509_Stack())
original_file_content = smime.verify(
    SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio_der(BIO.MemoryBuffer(p7m)),
    flags=SMIME.PKCS7_NOVERIFY
)
```

You can use `SMIME.load_pkcs7`, `SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio`, `SMIME.load_pkcs7_der` instead of `SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio_der` according to your use case: in-memory (`_bio`) or on file system .p7m file, and PEM or DER (`_der`) format.

Answer (score 0):

The best reference I found to sign and unsign is the M2Crypto tests here:

http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_smime.py

```
def test_sign(self):
    buf = BIO.MemoryBuffer(self.cleartext)
    s = SMIME.SMIME()
    s.load_key('tests/signer_key.pem', 'tests/signer.pem')
    p7 = s.sign(buf, SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED)
    assert len(buf) == 0
    assert p7.type() == SMIME.PKCS7_SIGNED, p7.type()
    assert isinstance(p7, SMIME.PKCS7), p7
    out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    p7.write(out)

    buf = out.read()

    assert buf[:len('-----BEGIN PKCS7-----')] == '-----BEGIN PKCS7-----'
    buf = buf.strip()
    assert buf[-len('-----END PKCS7-----'):] == '-----END PKCS7-----', buf[-len('-----END PKCS7-----'):]
    assert len(buf) > len('-----END PKCS7-----') + len('-----BEGIN PKCS7-----')

    s.write(out, p7, BIO.MemoryBuffer(self.cleartext))
    return out

def test_verify(self):
    s = SMIME.SMIME()

    x509 = X509.load_cert('tests/signer.pem')
    sk = X509.X509_Stack()
    sk.push(x509)
    s.set_x509_stack(sk)

    st = X509.X509_Store()
    st.load_info('tests/ca.pem')
    s.set_x509_store(st)

    p7, data = SMIME.smime_load_pkcs7_bio(self.signed)

    assert isinstance(p7, SMIME.PKCS7), p7
    v = s.verify(p7, data)
    assert v == self.cleartext

    t = p7.get0_signers(sk)
    assert len(t) == 1
    assert t[0].as_pem() == x509.as_pem(), t[0].as_text()
```

Be carefull with the documentation (http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/doc/howto.smime.html) because it is not updated.

See this patch:

https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13020